Query referenced a calculated column which does not hold any data because there's an error in it's expression
I'm getting the following error message whenever I try to view/drill down the makings of particular values in a Power Pivot in Excel 2016:

The query did not run or the data model could not be accessed. Here's the error message we got; the query referenced calculated column [Last Visit(Year)] which does not hold any data

I had deleted the column, Last Visit, after realizing it's not needed.
Any leads would be appreciated.
I'm actually clueless on how to go about it
